# Async Functions with Node Cron

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, cron

I have to run an async function written with Puppeteer (it's a bot) and I want to run that function every 60 seconds. The issue is that the async function (bot) runs for 2 min and so node cron automatically executes another async function which leads to 2 bot and 5s later it will launch another instance of this function.

What i want is to run 1st time then wait for 60s And after that execute it again. I'm so confused, it's my first NodeJS project.

```
const cron = require("node-cron")

cron.schedule("*/60 * * * * *", async () => {
    try {
        console.log(BotVote("Royjon94", "1"))
    }
    catch {
        console.log('error 404')
    }
})
```

Comment: Well, i don't know about cron in node but you are not awaiting `BotVote` function. If that function does an async operation you should be awaiting that.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure `cron` is suitable for this kind of job. But basically you can achieve the same behavior with a basic while loop and a promise to await.

```js
function delay(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function BotVote() {
  await new Promise(r => setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("voting");
    r();
  })) // for illusturation purpose  
}


async function worker() {
  let i = 0;
  let keepGoing = true;
  while (keepGoing) {
    await BotVote()
    await delay(600); // imagine it's 1minute.
    i++;
    if (i === 3) keepGoing = false; // decide when you stop
  }
}

worker();
```

Comment: Eldar, well thanks for your reply i've give it a try and it works as I wanted. VeryThankful for your help, have a good day.